# Trigonometric Integration + Series

Tags: trigonometry, integration, summation

I am doing an integration question:

$$\int \frac{1-\cos^{2m}x}{1-\cos^2x}$$

So I have to show that $$\frac{1-\cos^{2m}x}{1-\cos^2x}=1+\cos^2x+\cos^4x+...+\cos^{2(m-1)}$$

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: could you do it if it was $\frac{1-u^{m}}{1-u}$, where $u = \cos^{2}(x)$?